# why carousel of materializecss and *ngFor not working together dynamicaly to get images and content items

Tags: angular, typescript, materialize

> this is my component ts file and my component html file. the console from chrome does not return any error but just the carousel doesn't appear. the backend data is returned fine when i see it on network tab of chrome. Also the the carousel doesnt appear when i use simple JSON to retrieve it from ts file. What am i missing?

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AdminService, } from "../../services/admin.service";
import{ DataSharingService } from "../../services/data-sharing.service";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import * as M from 'node_modules/materialize-css';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-car-selection',
  templateUrl: './car-selection.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./car-selection.component.css']
})
export class CarSelectionComponent implements OnInit {
 
  
  vehicletypes: any[];
  options = {fullWidth: true, indicators: true};

  constructor(
    private admin : AdminService,
    private dataSharingService:DataSharingService,
    private router: Router ) {
  }
  
  ngOnInit() {
  this.getvehicleType();
  this.initialized();
  }

  initialized(){
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel');
    var instances = M.Carousel.init(elems, this.options);
  }

  
  getvehicleType() 
  {
  this.admin.getVehicleType().subscribe(
      result => {
        this.vehicletypes = result;
      
          }
  )}
    
  submit(sendInfo)
    {
      this.dataSharingService.sendSelectedCar(sendInfo);
      this.router.navigateByUrl('choose-location');

    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:aqua">
    <div *ngFor="let vehicletypes of vehicletypes; let i=index"  (click)="submit(vehicletypes)">
        <div class="carousel carousel-slider center">
            <div class="carousel-item amber black-text">  
                <h5>{{vehicletypes.name}}</h5>
                    <img class="responsive-img" [src]="vehicletypes.picturePath">
                <div class="carousel-fixed-item center">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col s6"><ul><li><a class="btn-floating red"><i class="material-icons">people</i></a>{{vehicletypes.capacity}}</li></ul></div> 
                        <div class="col s6"><ul><li><a class="btn-floating red"><i class="material-icons">attach_money</i></a>{{vehicletypes.price}}</li></ul></div> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try to console vehicletypes  after this.vehicletypes = result; and make sure picturPath is there

Comment: this may be not the bug but please rename the ngFor-Iteration-Element to something different than the same as the array itself.

Comment: @NarendraMongiya it returns the data when i alert it! [{"id":1,"name":"blueVan","description":"blue","price":120,"picturePath":"http://example.com/uploads/blueVan.jpeg","capacity":12},{"id":2,"name":"redVan","description":"red","price":180,"picturePath":"http://example.com/uploads/redVan.jpeg","capacity":8}

Comment: @Joniras i did as you said but it doesn't work either!

Comment: Try to output {{verhicleTypes| json}} somewhere in your html. This gives you a clue if the data is visible in the html.

Comment: It is not visible. but when i remove the carousel class it works. which isnt the case i want.